# Implementing Jarvis Binary Search in Chan's algorithm

Tags: algorithm, binary-search, computational-geometry, convex-hull

Both [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chan%27s_algorithm#Overview) and [Chan's paper](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF02712873.pdf) state that once Graham's scan has been done to the $n//m$ subsets of our original set $P$, since each subhull is ordered from least to most CCW rotation from its lowest point, we can perform Jarvis March using a binary search on each subhill.

From Wikipedia:

> .... The convex hull of the set $Q_k$, $C_k$, is known and contains at most $m$ points (listed in a clockwise or counter-clockwise order), which allows to compute $f(p_{i},Q_{k})$ in $O(\log m)$ time by binary search.

From Chan's paper:

> Since tangent finding takes logarithmic time for a convex polygon by binary or Fibonacci search [5], [25***] (the dual problem is to intersect a convex polygon with a ray), the time required for a wrapping step is then O ((n/m) log m). [pg 2]
> also,
> compute the point $q_i\in P_i$ that maximizes $\angle p_{k-1}p_k q_i$ by performing a binary search on the vertices of conv(Pi) [pg 3]

I don't know how to do this.

I have looked online for a more complete explanation, but most sources skip the actual implementation of binary jarvis march. I have looked at a few implementations, but their code and implementations of Chan's algortithm on GitHub were not easy to read.

*** I have tried looking through "Computational Geometry: An Introduction - F Peparata, M I Shamos", which was [25] in the first quote Chans paper. Unfortunately, I could not find binary Jarvis. I am not experienced in computational geometry either.

I would greatly appreciate a python implementation of what I'm calling binary jarvis, or at least pseudocode explaining how to write it.

Answer (score 0):

The inner loop of the **regular** Jarvis march scans **all** points in the set P to find the next point of the convex hull. This next point is chosen based on the polar angle between the segment [CurrentPoint, NextPoint] and the OX axis - this angle must be minimized.

However, the **variant** of the Jarvis march, used in the Chan algorithm, deals with a number of **already created** convex polygons with vertices, stored in the counterclockwise order. So, the inner loop of this variant doesn't need to scan all the points of these polygons - it can use (kind of) binary search to find **tangent lines** between the current point and each of these polygons, and then choose the line with minimal polar angle.

As for the Python source code, [this one](https://gist.github.com/tixxit/252229) looks good to me. It's not simple, however the Chan algorithm is not simple either.

Also, please see this [answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/138901/upper-and-lower-tangent-line-to-convex-hull-from-a-point) for a similar question - sorry to say, there are no code/pseudocode there.